# Using R, How to Convert a Factor into a Date without losing the year?

Tags: r, as.date

When I read in a data file using R, a Date variable is a Factor.

For example, let epc hold the  data set. Then if we look at the structure of the first date, we get

> str(epc$Date[1])
>   Factor w/ 1 level "16/12/2006": 1

If you were to convert this to a character, as.character(epc$Date[1]), you'd get exactly the same thing: "16/12/2006"

No matter what I've tried, I can't convert this type of object into a valid date.

if the date is "16/12/2006" (which I'm assuming is Dec. 16th, 2006), then as.Date(epc_full$Date[1]) gives  "0016-12-20" -- the full year is lost.

I've tried many different things, e.g., first converting the date into a character, trying different versions of as.Date(), etc., but I keep getting exactly the  same result when the input is "16/12/2006"

What's the trick here?

Comment: can you provide a `dput` of at least a `head` of the factor variable?

Comment: Can you try class(epc$Date[1]) to see what type is used?

Comment: You'll also need to specify the format: `as.Date(thing, format="%d/%m/%Y") assuming it's m/d/Y format.

Answer (score 0):

So first, for some reason this is being read in as a factor with a level that is labeled "16/12/2006".  You are converting this to a character, so I'll start there.

There are a number of ways to do this, but I think the easiest is to use the lubridate package.

```
#Install package
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

yourTextDate <- "16/12/2006"

yourDate <- dmy(yourTextDate)

yourDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want a `Date` class, then:

```
as.Date(s, format='%d/%m/%Y')
## [1] "2006-12-16"
class(.Last.value)
## [1] "Date"
```

So you can convert the entire column of dates with:

```
as.Date(epc$Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

This should work whether it is a character or factor.

`lubridate` works well as well, but if you're sticking with base *R*, this works well too.